# Parse xrandr output to get available resolution

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have xrandr output as follows

```
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected 1600x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 440mm x 250mm
   1600x900      60.00*+
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

How can compose a bash script to get the available resolutions from xrandr result above.

for example
`the-script HDMI1` will output only

```
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

I have tried

```
xrandr | awk '/HDMI1.*?/,/.*connected [0-9].*/'
```

while the result is close to what I want, but using

```
xrandr | awk '/VGA1.*?/,/.*connected [0-9].*/'
```

does not list the resolutions under VGA1 output.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler version of the awk command for the script:

```
xrandr |
  awk -v monitor="^$MONITOR connected" '/connected/ {p = 0}
    $0 ~ monitor {p = 1}
    p'
```

Bottom to top:

- `p` tells awk to run the default action (printing) depending on whether it's true or false)
- if the line matches the monitor and is connected we set `p` to true
- for all other monitor lines we set `p` to false

Answer (score 2):

Well, figure it out,

```
#!/bin/bash
#usage the-script XRANDR_OUTPUT_NAME
#e.g the-script HDMI1
MONITOR=$1;
xrandr | grep -v disconnected | \
awk '{ 
        if(/^'$MONITOR' connected/) { 
                print $0; 
                m="t"; 
        } else if(m == "t"){ 
                if (/^[a-zA-Z]/){
                        exit 
                } else { 
                        print $0
                } 
        }
}'
```

Hope this will help some one.

Comment: Simpler: `xrandr | awk -v monitor="^$MONITOR connected" '/disconnected/ {p = 0} $0 ~ monitor {p = 1} p' `

Comment: yeah, very much simpler, can you repost it as answer, to be selected as solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrandr --query | gawk -v monitor="$1" '
  $0 ~ monitor && $0 !~ /disconnected/ {
    do {print}
    while (getline > -1 && $0 ~ /^[[:blank:]]/)
  }
'
```

Usage:

```
$ ./the_script LVDS-1
LVDS-1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 303mm x 190mm
   1440x900      60.00*+  59.89    50.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05
```

---

If you don't have GNU awk, you may need to replace `[[:blank:]]` with `[ \t]`